# Convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n (e-(1+\frac{1}{n})^n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

Does $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n (e-(1+\frac{1}{n})^n)$ converge absolutely, conditionally, or diverge?

Attempt:

Yes, by the ratio test we have
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{(-1)^{n+1} (e-(1+\frac{1}{n+1})^{n+1})}{(-1)^n (e-(1+\frac{1}{n})^n)}\right| = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{-e+(1+\frac{1}{n+1})^{n+1})}{e-(1+\frac{1}{n})^n}\right| = \left| \frac{ -e + e }{ e - e} \right| = 0$$

So the series converges absolutely.

Comment: That's $\frac00$ at the end there, not $0$.

Comment: Looks like an indeterminate form if you apply the ratio test; maybe try something else.

Comment: it's alternating and $(1+1/n)^n$ increases to $e$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Taylor series we get:

$$\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=\exp\left(n\ln\left(1+\frac1n\right)\right)=\exp\left(1-\frac1{2n}+\mathcal O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\right)$$
so the given general term of the series denoted by $u_n$ is
$$u_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{2n}+\mathcal O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$$
so the series $\sum u_n$ is convergent since it's sum of the convergent series $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{2n}$ using the Leibniz theorem and the convergent series $\sum \mathcal O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$ by comparison with the Riemann series.

**Remark** This series isn't absolutely convergent since
$$|u_n|\sim_\infty\frac1{2n}$$
and all we know that the harmonic series $\sum\frac1n$ is divergent.